# Потоки С++ Builder

Tags: многопоточность, c++builder

Нужно запустить функцию в отдельном потоке. Желательно средствами билдера (не обращаясь к WinAPI на прямую).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запуск потока делается с помощью класса TThread.

```
class TSomeThread : public TThread
{
public:
    __fastcall TSomeThread(bool CreateSuspended) {};
};

void __fastcall TSomeThread::Execute()
{
    // TODO: Здесь Ваш код потока
}
```

Собственно порождение потока:

```
TSomeThread *SomeThread = new TSomeThread(false);
```

Смотреть информацию вполне можно в справке IDE. Плюс в какой-то папке установки лежат примеры для потоков.

[Разработка многопоточных приложений в C++Builder](http://rxlib.ru/WinLesson/bles2_1.htm).

Comment: А.Я.Архангельский, "Программирование С++Builder 6", с. 459, М. "Издательство Бином", 2002